# Help with difficult 'group by' clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

need some your help with a query.

I have a table `Managers (ManagerId, ManagerName)`

I have a table `Statuses (StatusId, StatusName)`
*(There's about 10 statuses in that table)*

I have a table `Clients (ClientId, ClientName, ManagerId, StatusId, WhenAdded)`
*(`WhenAdded` is a datetime type)*

It's obvious that field `'ManagerId'` refers to a table `'Managers'` and field `'StatusId'` refers to a table `'Statuses'`.

User wants to get some statistics about Managers over a period of time (`from startDate to endDate using field 'WhenAdded'`) in the following table.

Columns:

`ManagerName, NumberOfClients, NumberOfClientsWithStatus1, NumberOfClientsWithStatus2, NumberOfClientsWithStatus3` and so on.

Number of columns with name `NumberOfClientsWithStatusI` where `i` is a number of statuses equal to number of rows in table `'Statuses'`.

How can I do that?

t-sql, sql server 2008 r2 express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ManagerName,
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfClients,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus3,
    ...
FROM
   Clients C
   JOIN
   Managers M ON C.ManagerId = M.ManagerId
   JOIN
   Statuses S ON C.StatusId = S.StatusId
WHERE
    M.WhenAdded BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY
    M.ManagerName
```

Note: there is no clean way to add arbritrary numbers of status columns in SQL (not just SQL Server) because its a fixed column output. You'd have to change the query for status, unless you deal with this in the client

Edit, after comment

```
SELECT
    ManagerName,
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfClients,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumberOfClientsWithStatus3,
    ...
FROM
   Managers M ON C.ManagerId = M.ManagerId
   LEFT JOIN
   Clients C
   LEFT JOIN
   Statuses S ON C.StatusId = S.StatusId
WHERE
    M.WhenAdded BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY
    M.ManagerName
```

Comment: gbn, what about managers that don't have a client over a period of time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `statuses` table will always contain a limited number of statuses, you can do this:

```
SELECT M.ManagerName,
       COUNT(C.ClientId) NumberOfClients,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.StatusId= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberOfClientsWithStatus1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.StatusId= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberOfClientsWithStatus2,
       ...
  FROM Clients C
  JOIN Managers M on M.ManagerId = C.ManagerId
  JOIN Statuses S on S.StatusId = C.StatusId
 WHERE C.WhenAdded BETWEEN startDate AND endDate 
 GROUP BY ManagerName
```